# Silverstripe 3: Add logo image into custom email template

Tags: php, silverstripe

I have a custom email template which I am using as the validation email when a user signs up to my silverstripe site but it won't display images.

I want to add my logo at the end of the email but it will not render any image, will only load alt text.

My code to send the email:

```php
$email = MemberConfirmationEmail::create($this, $member);
$approve = Controller::join_links(
    Director::baseURL(),
    'member-approval',
    $member->ID,
    '?token=' . $member->ValidationKey
);
$email->setSubject('Registration Account Confirmation'));
$email->setTemplate('CustomMemberConfirmationEmail');
$email->populateTemplate(array('ApproveLink' => Director::absoluteURL($approve)));
$email->send();
```

This email template has an image tag in it with the image saved at:

`themes/mytheme/assets/images/mylogo.png`

All of this works perfectly fine except for rendering the image.

Am I missing something or saving it in the wrong place?

Answer (score 2):

When sending an email we need to make sure all our URLs are absolute URLs and not relative URLs.

We can do this by using `$AbsoluteLink` for links and appending `$AbsoluteBaseURL` to resources.

In SilverStripe 3 we can do this for a resource with the following:

```
<img src="{$AbsoluteBaseURL}{$ThemeDir}/assets/images/mylogo.png" alt="$SiteConfig.Title" />
```